# How to add a paramater to a function in a class with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, jsdoc

So let's set the table here.

I have a class called Command and in that class I have an object as the parameter with 3 properties `(name, description, execute())`

```js
class Command {
  /**
   *
   * @param {Object} opts
   * @param {String} opts.name
   * @param {String} opts.description
   * @param {Function} opts.execute
   */
  constructor(opts) {
    this.name = opts.name;
    this.description = opts.description;
    this.execute = opts.execute;
  }
}
```

The `execute` property is a function and I want to pass in another set of JSDoc line for the parameter in those function.

It should generally work like this

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "Hello!",
  description: "----",
  /**
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Array} args
   */
  execute(message, client, args) {},
};
```

Is it possible to do this, or do I have to switch over to TypeScript?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `typedef` and `property`, but you need to write it on all files you use it, it's better if you use a `tsconfig.json`.

you dont need typescript all you need is a `tsconfig.json`, but ofcourse typescript would be better.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

```js
/**
 * The complete Triforce, or one or more components of the Triforce.
 * @typedef {Object} WishGranter~Triforce
 * @property {boolean} hasCourage - Indicates whether the Courage component is present.
 * @property {boolean} hasPower - Indicates whether the Power component is present.
 * @property {boolean} hasWisdom - Indicates whether the Wisdom component is present.
 */

/**
 * A class for granting wishes, powered by the Triforce.
 * @class
 * @param {...WishGranter~Triforce} triforce - One to three {@link WishGranter~Triforce} objects
 * containing all three components of the Triforce.
 */
function WishGranter(triforce) {}
```

Comment: How do you use the `tsconfig.json` way? 
Curious since there's nothing in the typescript docs (specifically for tsconfig.json) that mention declaration files